# How to wait for page load to complete in Chrome browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What is the command in webdriver to wait for page to load fully before performing action on the page in CHROME browser?

PageLoadTimeOut is not waiting for the  page load to complete in Chrome whereas it is working fine in firefox.

In Chrome, if webelement is there on the page, webdriver is performing the action on webelement while page is getting loaded. This is causing scripts to fail randomly with exception 'element is not clickable'.

Please let me know if there is any solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom wait methods for an element to be enable or visible on the page.

For Example create a custom method `isElementEnable` using following code:

```
driver.findElement(locator).isEnabled();
```

Or use the following code to check if the element is visible on page:

```
driver.findElement(locator).isDisplayed();
```

pass your element `locator` as input parameter to the method.

Or Alternatively use implicit wait:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(number_of_seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I'm using these wait methods currently. But still in chrome, webdriver doesn't wait for the specified time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `JavaScriptExecuter.executeScript` to get `document.readyState`,to compare it to `complete`,as a condition to WebDriverWait.Like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new ...;
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return (JavaScriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, with `Chrome` if you have a alert on page,you will get a UnhandledAlertException.And this will not occur for `Firefox`

Answer (score -3):

It's a really old question, but anyone having the same question might find this useful:

For chromedriver, it is best to use `sleep` method:

```
import time

# some of your code

time.sleep(2)
# here your program will wait for two seconds

# rest of your code
```

You can find an appropriate time span that will ensure your page loads and pass that time as parameter. But using too big time will make program slower.